# Static header covers body in Firefox, isn't static in IE

Tags: html, css, html-table

The CSS that tells it to stay static

```
#fruko {
            position: fixed;
        }
        #links {
            position: fixed;
        }
```

The HTML where the Div tags are

```
<td width="225px"><div id="fruko"><p><a href="#top" style="text-decoration: none"><font color="Red" size="8">Fruko, inc.</font></a></p></div></td>
        <td><div id="links"><table border="5" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><a href="#apps" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="6" color="Red">Apps</font></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="#programs" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="6" color="Red">Programs</font></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="#webs" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="6" color="Red">Websites</font></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="#news" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="6" color="Red">News</font></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="#social" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="6" color="Red">Social</font></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="#about" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="6" color="Red">About</font></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div></td>
```

Also the table in side the main table at the top doesn't stretch in Firefox but it does in IE.

Test it for yourself [here](http://fruko.webs.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Internet Explorer conditional comments to load styles specifically tailored to IE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

This would not solve the root of the problem in that one should use generally cross-browser CSS, but it does efficiently meet needs such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a little confusing.  You are saying 'static' header, which is a valid css position e.g. `position:static`, but you are declaring `position:fixed` which has a completely different effect and it's worth doing research into the difference if you're unclear.

Adding `position:fixed` to an element effectively takes it out of the flow of elements and makes it 'fixed' relative to the browser window.  All the elements below it will shift up like it's not even there.

Any IE problems you have are probably related to the fact the the whole page is built with tables which can be problematic and inconsistent between browsers.  Also, older versions of IE don't do `position:fixed`